# (Excel VBA) - Draw from cell text in a macro

Tags: vba, excel, text, cell

I'm trying to build a small macro that allows the user to format multiple different documents at once.

I would like for the user to be able to enter into a particular cell within the document containing the macro a particular piece of text.

I then want for this piece of text to be able to be drawn upon in the macro while affecting a different document.

For instance, a code to add another column might say

```
Worksheets(1).Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
```

Instead of specifying the column (A), I would like it to draw on a value in the host document. For instance, the user types "G" into the particular cell, and then clicks a button to run the macro, and the macro will dynamically know to affect column G in all excel documents it targets based off of the value in the host document.

I hope this makes sense.

Any suggestions for the sort of functions I should be looking at to make this work?

Comment: `Worksheets(1).Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").value & "1").EntireColumn.Insert`  Where B1 on Sheet1 is the location of the column.

Comment: The problem is that Excel seems to then draw upon the value in the document it's trying to edit. In this example I run the macro from a host document in which the value of B1 is G, but the value of B1 in the excel document being targeted is F, the new column will inserted at F rather than G.

Comment: Then add the Workbook Reference `ThisWorkbook.`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot.

Comment: As an extension to this - how would I modify this to move a piece of text from a specific cell to a different worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Any suggestions on the sort of functions I should be looking at?"
Here's a few...

To get the value which is entered...

If the cell will always be in the same address, say A1:

```
' Define a string variable and set it equal to value in A1
Dim cellText as String
cellText = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
```

or instead of using `Range` you can also use `Cells` which takes a row and column number.

```
cellText = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value
```

If the cell changes then you may need to look into the `Find` function to look for a label/heading next to the input cell. Then you can use it (easily with `Cells`) to reference the input...

Once you have this variable, you can do what you like with it.

To put this value into cell B3 in another (open) workbook named "MyWorkbook", and a sheet named "MySheet" you can do:

```
Application.Workbooks("MyWorkbook").Sheets("MySheet").Range("B3").Value = cellText
```

**To insert a column at `cellText`, do**

```
Application.Workbooks("MyWorkbook").Sheets("MySheet").Range(cellText & "1").EntireColumn.Insert
```

Notably here, the `&` concatonates the strings together, so if

`cellText="B"`

then

`cellText & "1" = "B1"`

Further to your comment about moving values between sheets, see my first example here, but always refer to the same workbook. If you find yourself repeatedly typing something like 
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").<other stuff>`

then you can use the `With` shorthand.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")

    ' Starting anything with a dot "." now assumes the with statement first
    .Range("A1").Value = .Range("A2").Value
    .Range("B1").Value = .Range("B2").Value

End With
```

Important to note is that this code has no data validation to check the cell's value before using it! Simply trying to insert a column based on a value which could be *anything* is sure to make the macro crash within its first real world use!